# 404 return for every update request in livewire

Tags: laravel, livewires

I have put the project in subfolder and use server.php and .htaccess to  handle request from there , First pages of livewire component works fine (those whose route are defined in web.php) other update post request didt work ,
The project works fine in PHP artisan serve,

I am using xammp , PHP 8.1, livewire3,
in HandleRequests add /lmapnext

```
  lmapnext\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\Mechanisms\HandleRequests\HandleRequests.php

function boot()
    {
        app($this::class)->setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
            return Route::post('/lmapnext/livewire/update', $handle)->middleware('web');
        });

        $this->skipRequestPayloadTamperingMiddleware();
    }
```

````
   in config/livewire 
   'asset_url'  => '/lmapnext/livewire/livewire.js',```
````

```
.htaccess
```

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

```

how can i solve this issue i have to use subfolder method

tried cache clear , this question is posted many time but didt found any soultion

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution to your problem (and mine) at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/livewire-livewiremessagename-returns-404-on-deployed-site?page=1&replyId=907910

Inside the boot mehotd of a Service Provider (I selected in the RouteServiceProvider for consistency) you add the next code:

```
\Livewire\Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
        return Route::post('[subfolder]/livewire/update', $handle);
});
```

It worked for me, hope it works for you.